# Changing the color of dynamically created buttons not using clicked at event

Tags: c#, button, dynamic, background-color

I have added buttons to a grid layout I created.  Here is the code for that.

```
        int nodeIndex = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < usedRows; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(nodes[nodeIndex++], j, i);
            }
        }
```

Later on in the application I want to be able to change the color of a button at a specified position.  Basically change the back round color of the button at position i,j. How would I get access to that specific button?  I am using winforms.  Is there something like

```
button = this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.GetChildAtPosition(j, i)
```

Comment: There is a getControlFromPosition for the [tableLayoutpanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcontrolfromposition(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something along these lines.

```
button = this.tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(j, i);
button.BackColor = Color.BLACK;
```

Answer (score 0):

So first you want to able to find the control and conveniently there is a method called FindControl() that can do just that

MSDN link for reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Second you want to be able to change the color of the button once you find it.

For buttons you probably want to use the BackColor property.

Again MSDN link for reference:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The trick is going to be finding the control and then working with that control as an object to change the color. Don't forget that you can cast the control to a button type once you find it, which should give you access to the BackColor property.